# How to avoid coupling using custom type in web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soa

I'm going to develop a webservice (likely in WCF) and probably several parameters  passed to the exposed methods will be custom type parameters.

Do you have any hints on how to avoid *breaking* SOA decoupling and reach my target?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it : webservices exposes WSDL, where custom types are defined. I don't see why you should break SOA with that ?

Comment: @Styx31: this is the question (and probably you already replied): will I "break" something?

Comment: And then: how the client can use my custom "type" if it doesn't know it? It is enough WSDL to describe in an interoperable way any type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSDL defines interoperable contract with :

- endpoint and action describing how to communicate with webservice
- types using and xsd schema

The xml schema (xsd) describes types : xml elements, value types using xml types and so on.

So if you can describe all your types using Xml Schema, then it will be ok. .NET enforce your type can be serialized to xml, then it is possible to expose it via a webservice.

On the client side, there are often libraries which can read WSDL and deduct/generate classes in their language to serialize/deserialize messages to/from the service. But any human can also read the contract and the writ